# read data from a scanned document(pdf or other format) for db persistence purposes

Tags: php, pdf, text

I am working on an app that will need to read data from a scanned document in pdf format or other formats and save it to a database. I have searched but nothing I need right now. I was wondering if someone out there has an API or some other solution that can help me.

The actual app is PHP if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: it might be indeed. I will check it out. thanks